# $f \in A[X]\backslash \{0\}$ can be written as $f=af_0$, where $f_0 \in A[X]$ is primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Show that any $f \in A[X]\backslash \{0\}$  can be written as $f=af_0$, where $f_0 \in A[X]$ is primitive.

I know how to prove for the case $A = \mathbb{Z}$ be choosing a as the biggest number which divide all coefficients in f. But this doesn't work for the general A. Can anyone give me a hint? Many thanks

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think you may need stronger assumptions on $A$. The notion of the gcd of elements doesn't necessarily make sense in an arbitrary integral domain. It does, however, in a UFD or a GCD domain, in which case the proof will proceed similarly as for the case $A=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @kccu you don't need the concept of greatest common divisor to make sense, you only need maximal common divisors to exist.

Comment: @Arthur I stand corrected.